# Using parameter makes the SQL run very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to get the account information of those employees located in America. If an employee doesn't have location information, it means the employee lives in Asia.

```
exec sp_executesql N'select top 1 * from Account where /
     exists( select * from employee where Acc_id=emp_id and @emp_loc=''Asia'') /
     or (not exists (select * from emplyee where Acc_id=emp_id ) and /
     @emp_loc=''Asia'')'N' @emp_loc varchar(10)',@emp_loc='America'
```

The above query takes more than 5 mins to execute.

If I hard-code the parameter. It just takes 1 sec.

```
SELECT top 1 * 
FROM Account
WHERE exists(
              SELECT * 
              FROM employee 
              WHERE Acc_id=emp_id 
              AND 'America'='Asia'
            )
       OR (not exists(
                       SELECT * 
                       FROM employee
                       WHERE Acc_id=emp_id
                     ) 
          AND 'America'='Asia'
          )
```

Why using parameter let the perfomance be very slow?

Comment: `AND 'Asia'='Asia'` is pretty weird condition

Comment: employee & emplyee? Two different tables or is that a typo?

Comment: I just type the parameter for test performance. So it look very strange.

Comment: to @AbdurrahmanMubeenAli It just one table. because I can't use join in this SQL

Comment: Then the WHERE condition seems useless. As the same SELECT queries are used with EXIST and NOT EXIST.

Comment: The Asia can be anything.
I already change the example for the useless problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the condition filter is `where Acc_id=emp_id and emp_loc=@emp_loc`
Try it..!!

Comment: But in the code structure, I can't use join to the code.
**That's my question why use parameter will take much time to execute it ?**